# How do I disable Flask 308 redirect for trailing slash?

Tags: python, http, flask, werkzeug

I have such endpoints

```py
@app.route('/values', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def operation_types():
    return '', 200


@app.route('/values/', methods=['GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
@app.route('/values/<code>', methods=['GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def operation_type_(code: str = ''):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return '', 200
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        return '', 200
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        return '', 201
    return '', 405
```

I want the app to behave like this

```
GET /values         # lists all values
POST /values        # adds a new value

GET /values/123     # gets a value
DELETE /values/123  # deletes a value
PUT /values/123     # updates a value
```

and I also want this, to be treated as the later:

```
GET /values/        # gets a value with code ""
DELETE /values/     # deletes a value with code ""
PUT /values/        # updates a value with code ""
```

In any other case I want to get `404` if the route is missing, or `405` if method is not allowed.

But here's my problem:

```
DELETE  /values  # this should return 405, because method isn't allowed for /values, only for /values/
```

But instead I get `308`, with `Location:` header redirecting me to `/values/` and also flask renderes wierd HTML body from Werkzeug.

**I want to disable this automatic redirect completely**, I don't want flask to do any kind of redirects for me.

PS: I tried setting `strict_slashes`, but then `GET /values/` is being mistaken for `GET /values`.
PS: I know I can add `DELETE` to the first endpoint `methods`, but that only works for a single endpoint; and I want to set it in the whole application.

Comment: This is expected behavior. `The canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. It’s similar to a folder in a file system. If you access the URL without a trailing slash (/projects), Flask redirects you to the canonical URL with the trailing slash (/projects/)`  [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/rtd/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior). This need to be handled at user design level or a check on  `request.referrer`.

Comment: @simpleApp But these aren't two notations of the same endpoint! `/projects` loads all projects in my case, and `/projects/` load the single project, for which the parameter is empty name. It works for 200 and 201; but I can't get it to work with 405. Besides, I don't care for what the documentation says, I want to run `DELETE /projects/` and get 405, not 308. I want to handle the redirects myself; currently Flask is ruining it for me.

Comment: on way is define , not supported endpoints and let flask not redirect(its base functionality). `@app.route('/values', methods=['DELETE'])
def operation_types_no_supported():
    return '', 405`